Green's function of non self-adjoint operators
I'm trying to understand how Green's function applies to non self-adjoint operators, suppose an arbitrary 2nd-order inhomogeneous ODE with constant coefficients:
$$ ay''(x) + by'(x) + c = g(x) $$
and homogeneous B.C $y(x_1)=y(x_2)=0$.
I read somewhere that the Green’s function in such cases can still satisfy some continuity and discontinuity conditions, but I don't get how!
Going through the derivation of the solution to an ODE using Green's function, I see that we assume that the linear operator is self-adjoint in order to make this crucial step:
$$ < \mathcal{L} u(x) | G(x,s) > \quad = \quad  <  u(x) | \mathcal{L}^{\dagger} G(x,s) > $$
and also when deriving the continuity conditions themselves, the first thing that we do is we assume that the linear operator can be written in Sturm-Liouville Form
$$ \mathcal{L} = \frac{d}{dx} \Bigl[ p(x) \frac{d}{dx} \Bigr] + q(x)  $$
which implies that it is self-adjoint!
So how can we even apply Green's function to any ODE with a non self-adjoint operator? how can it still satisfy the continuity conditions?
